# Cannot find NetLogo model through command line

Tags: command-line, netlogo

I'm trying to get to grips with command line operations of NetLogo on a Windows 10 machine. I want to run the Fire.nlogo model provided.

I set the directory with `cd C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2`

Then I try to run a simple experiment called experiment1 which I've written beforehand in BehaviourSpace

```
netlogo-headless --model Fire.nlogo --experiment experiment1
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2\Fire.nlogo (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromURI(Source.scala:121)
        at org.nlogo.fileformat.AbstractNLogoFormat.$anonfun$sections$1(NLogoFormat.scala:37)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
        at org.nlogo.fileformat.AbstractNLogoFormat.sections(NLogoFormat.scala:36)
        at org.nlogo.fileformat.AbstractNLogoFormat.sections$(NLogoFormat.scala:34)
        at org.nlogo.fileformat.NLogoFormat.sections(NLogoFormat.scala:16)
        at org.nlogo.api.ModelFormat.load(ModelFormat.scala:53)
        at org.nlogo.api.ModelFormat.load$(ModelFormat.scala:51)
        at org.nlogo.fileformat.NLogoFormat.load(NLogoFormat.scala:16)
        at org.nlogo.api.FormatterPair.load(ModelLoader.scala:26)
        at org.nlogo.api.ModelLoader.readModel(ModelLoader.scala:60)
        at org.nlogo.api.ModelLoader.readModel$(ModelLoader.scala:57)
        at org.nlogo.api.ConfigurableModelLoader.readModel(ModelLoader.scala:90)
        at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:491)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.newWorkspace$1(Main.scala:18)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:21)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Main.scala:12)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Main.scala:12)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
        at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I notice that the output gives the path as `C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2\Fire.nlogo`but the model is actually located at `C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2\app\models\Sample Models\Earth Science\Fire.nlogo`

Though I seem to be following the tutorials as they're written here https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look suggests that you need to give the full file path to the `--model` argument.  So the command would look like:

```
netlogo-headless --model "C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2\app\models\Sample Models\Earth Science\Fire.nlogo" --experiment experiment1
```

Since you have set `cd C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2` you can probably go with

```
netlogo-headless --model "app\models\Sample Models\Earth Science\Fire.nlogo" --experiment experiment1
```

Alternatively, you can go to the directory that contains the model you want to run and instead provide the path (again with quotes) to the .bat file

```
"c:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.2\netlogo-headless.bat" --model Fire.nlogo --experiment experiment1
```

Comment: Great, thank you, I'm unfamiliar with command line which isn't helping. I presume I could apply the same logic to write the output table to a different folder than the location of the model?

Comment: Yes, that will work.  BTW, the quotes are necessary only if there are spaces in the filename or path.